# Using Apache to host files in multiple HDDs

Tags: apache

I have Windows version of XAMPP installed in `C:\xampp`.

All works well, however I am building a Netflix clone and all of my material (Shows/Movies/etc) are located in external HDDs (e.g.: `E:\` and `F:\`).

Is there a way to keep site in `C:\` while having access to `E:\` and `F:\` ? Basically all I need is to provide video src full path to `E:\movie.mkv` or `F:\movie.mkv` but when I do it now - blank screen is shown.

I am only aware of solution where I could merge two HDDs into one (Dynamic HDD) which would then share same drive letter and change `DocumentRoot` to that letter. I would like to avoid such setup however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something "streaming" the file to the enduser, there's no problem: your php,jsp or whatever you're using just need to have access to the file, regardless where it is, reand and stream it.

If you're just planning to show the content of the folder itself, you can create an Alias to each root folder. You can refer to the official documentation for the details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for setting me on the right path (no pun intended). For those who need the answer:

httpd.conf:

```
Alias /disk1 "E:"
<Directory "E:">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /disk2 "F:"
<Directory "F:">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```